# Is it necessary to use LocationManager.requestLocationUpdates and LocationManager.removeUpdates() for Google Maps?

Tags: android, google-maps, geolocation, google-maps-android-api-2

I created an app with an GoogleMapView. In order to reduce battery consumption, I want to stop the location requests, when the app is not opened. I found that this can be done with the LocationManager. For example like this:

```
@Override
public void onPause() {
    locationManager.removeUpdates(this);
    super.onPause();
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, true), minUpdateTime, minUpdateDistance, this, null);
    super.onResume();
}
```

But at the moment I am not using the LocationManager at all and the GoogleMapsView still manages to get the current location. I merely need to call `mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);` in my `OnMapReadyCallback()` function. So it seems like the GoogleMapsView implements its own sort of LocationManager which leads to the question, if it is necessary to create a LocationManager just to tell it to stop updating when the app is closed, or is it enough to call `mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(false);` in my `onPause()` function?

Comment: It sounds like you can get rid of your location requests.  You only need to request location updates if you need to process them in `onLocationChanged()`.  Also, you don't need to call `mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(false)`.  All you need to do is ensure you have the Location permission and then call `mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true)`  (no need to set it back to false at any point)

Comment: @DanielNugent, thanks for your help. I noticed when not  calling `mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(false)`, the location icon remains visible when I'm closing the app. So it seems like the app is still using the service in the background.